# finding indexes of common subarrays

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm, numpy

I have 2 large, unsorted arrays (structured set of xyz coordinates) and I'm trying to find the positions of all identical subarrays (common points consisting of 3 coordinates). Example:

```
a = array([[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5]])
b = array([[3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8]])
```

Here the correct subarray would be `[3, 4, 5]`, but more than one identical subarrays are possible. The correct indexes would be `[0,1]` for `a` and `[1,0]` for `b`.

I already implemented a pure python method by iterating over all points of one array and comparing them to every point of the other array, but this is extremely slow.

My question is, is there an efficient way to find the indexes for both arrays (preferably in numpy, because I need the arrays for further calculations)? Perhaps a rolling_window approach?

Comment: Are the subarrays in some sorted order like your example?

Comment: Do you want a general Python solution for iterables, or a solution specific to numpy? There is an easy linear time (in the number of subarrays) general Python method.

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing something - why is the answer [0, 1] for the first array and [1, 0] for the second?

Comment: @templatetypedef because the first array is row zero and the second is row one of a theoretical two-or-three-dimensional array (depending if you consider the subarrays to have dimension or not).

Comment: Belenon, the Python version you describe is quadratic time, mine is linear time -- you might be able to speed it up by a constant factor by doing it in numpy, but you can't reduce the time complexity.

Answer (score 2):

A general solution for Python iterables (not specific to numpy or arrays) that works in linear average time (O(n+m), n is the number of subarrays and m is the number of unique subarrays):

```
a = [[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5]]
b = [[3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8]]

from collections import defaultdict

indexmap = defaultdict(list)

for row, sublist in enumerate((a, b)):
    for column, item in enumerate(sublist):
        indexmap[tuple(item)].append((row, column))

repeats = dict((key, value) for key, value in indexmap.iteritems() if len(value) > 1)
```

Gives

```
{(3, 4, 5): [(0, 1), (1, 0)]}
```

If you don't need the double-row-indexes (index in the list and in the stored index) you can simplify the loop to

```
for row in (a, b):
    for column, item in enumerate(sublist):
        indexmap[tuple(item)].append(column)
```

as `a` will be processed before `b`, any duplicates will get numbered by row automatically:

```
{(3, 4, 5): [1, 0]}
```

With `repeats[key][rownum]` returning the column index for that row.

Comment: Would you be able to explain this? I can't figure out the O(n+m) algorithm and I don't know python so I can't work it out from the code.

Comment: Think of each "subarray" as being a single item, so each array is one dimensional, and together they are a two dimensional array. For each row in the two dimensional array, iterate over all the items, adding the column number to a mapping entry for that item. If an item appears once, the length of it's entry will be 1. If it appears twice, it will be 2, with the column for the first row at index zero, and the column for the second row will be at index one, since you iterated over the rows in that order. Then filter out all of the items with entries of length 1, leaving the repeated items.

Comment: @quasiverse So, iteration is O(n), the mapping operations are each O(1) on average, so doing them n times is O(n) average. Filtering the non-repeats out is O(m), where m is the number of items in the mapping, which is the number of unique items in the multidimensional array, so the overall operation is O(m+n) on average.

Answer (score 1):

I did a little further experimenting and found a numpy specific way to solve this:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.arange(24).reshape(2,4,3)
b = np.arange(24, 36).reshape(2,2,3)
```

Array b receives 2 entries from a:

```
b[1,0] = a[0,1]
b[0,1] = a[1,1]
```

Finding common entries:

```
c = np.in1d(a, b).reshape(a.shape)
d = np.in1d(b, a).reshape(b.shape)
```

Checking where common entries exist in all 3 coordinates:

```
indexesC = np.where(c[:,:,0] & c[:,:,1] & c[:,:,2])
indexesD = np.where(d[:,:,0] & d[:,:,1] & d[:,:,2])
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you map each sub-array to its position index in a hash table? So basically, you change your data structure. After that in linear time O(n), where n is the size of the biggest hash hash table, in one loop you can O(1) query each hash table and find out if you have same sub-array present in two or more hash tables.

Comment: @agf I suspected that after having posted the comment. Good work!